# Integrating 3rd party Shipping API in Magento

Tags: magento-2.1, rest-api, shipment

I was working on integrating a 3rd party REST API with our Magento installation. The 3rd party is a shipping company and the API they gave requirements to collect various shipment info (i.e shipper name, shipper address, consignee name, consignee address, tracking number, etc).

Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this? like a tutorial? I think I'm supposed to to do something when I create a shipment from Magento's back-end but I am not sure. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a new module.
There are two examples:

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/creating-a-shipping-method-in-magento-2/
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-create-shipping-method/

First method works, second I have not cheked yet.

Moreover, in your module, you shuld use observers when people create the order and then sent information to your shipping company.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about developing **magento** custom modules then i would recommend you to look at **magento** core **shipping module**. I hope you will get a lot from it.